# Loading multiple step files into the model, but they are not visible

Tags: c#, eyeshot

Ia loading multiple step files into the model, but they are not visible.
However when loading the step files one by one, they are visible. What is the problem...

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    List<ReadSTEP> stp_list = new List<ReadSTEP>();

    string Path = @"----directory----";
    System.IO.DirectoryInfo di = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(Path);

    foreach (var item in di.GetFiles())
    {
        stp_list.Add(new ReadSTEP(item.Name));                
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < stp_list.Count; i++)
    {                
        if (true)
        {
            stp_list[i].DoWork();
            stp_list[i].AddToScene(model1);
            Trace.WriteLine(stp_list[i].FileName + " is loaded");
        }
    }  

    model1.Invalidate();
    model1.ZoomFit();
}
```

Comment: I tried your code and it works fine after replacing item.Name with item.FullName, in this way: stp_list.Add(new ReadSTEP(item.FullName)).

Answer (score 1):

Step files can contain Blocks with the same name, so you can try in this way: https://devdept.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360017314360-Add-to-scene-as-single-object